# Unit test: How to get state after promise resolve?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

In this case, I mock **getArticlesFromDatabase** and make promise resolve a fakeData.

It is success that console: **setState articleGroup** recive data, but console: **get state** shows nothing.

How do I get state in **navList.test.js** when **setArticleGroup** setState ?

**navList.js**

```
setArticleGroup(){
    let that = this;

    getArticlesFromDatabase().then(function(value) {
        let sieveDataFromProps = _.filter(value, { 'type': that.props.sieve });
        let articleGroup = _.sortBy(sieveDataFromProps, ['updated_at']);

        that.setState({'articleGroup':articleGroup},function(){
            console.log('setState articleGroup:   ',articleGroup);
        });
    });

}
```

**navList.test.js**

```
it.only('function setArticleGroup() ', function () {

        let csrfData = require('../components/common/csrfData');
        let fakeData = [
            {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-33 08:34:33"},
            {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-22 08:34:22"},
            {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"",updated_at:"2018-01-00 08:34:33"},
            {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-11 08:34:11"}
        ];

        csrfData.getArticlesFromDatabase = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(fakeData));

        let app = shallow(<NavList sieve="info" />);
        app.instance().setArticleGroup();

        console.log('get state:     ',app.state().articleGroup);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could use **async/await** to solve this issue.
I only have to do, is wait till **setArticleGroup()** finished.

Add **promise** inside **setArticleGroup()** can also done the thing, but **async/await** can solve the problem without add new **promise**.

```
it('function setArticleGroup() ', async function () {

     let csrfData = require('../components/common/csrfData');
     let fakeData = [
         {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-33 08:34:33"},
         {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-22 08:34:22"},
         {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"",updated_at:"2018-01-00 08:34:33"},
         {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-11 08:34:11"}
     ];
     csrfData.getArticlesFromDatabase = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(fakeData));

     let app = shallow(<NavList sieve="info" />);

     await app.instance().setArticleGroup();
     const lengthOfSieveFakeData = 3;
     expect(app.state().articleGroup.length).to.equal(lengthOfSieveFakeData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise in `setArticleGroup()` function, because inside you have an async call to `getArticlesFromDatabase()`. Then in your test case you need to wait until `setArticleGroup()` function finish. I'm not sure which testing framework you used. If Jest, then you can read more about asnyc testing [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html).

**navList.js**

```
setArticleGroup(){
    let that = this;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getArticlesFromDatabase().then(function(value) {
            let sieveDataFromProps = _.filter(value, { 'type': that.props.sieve });
            let articleGroup = _.sortBy(sieveDataFromProps, ['updated_at']);

            that.setState({'articleGroup':articleGroup},function(){
                console.log('setState articleGroup:   ',articleGroup);
                // put resolve where you function finish
                resolve();
            });
            // you should use reject() for all cases when your function fail
        });
    });

}
```

**navList.test.js**

```
it.only('function setArticleGroup() ', function (done) {

        let csrfData = require('../components/common/csrfData');
        let fakeData = [
            {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-33 08:34:33"},
            {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-22 08:34:22"},
            {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"",updated_at:"2018-01-00 08:34:33"},
            {article:"",created_at:"2018-01-11 07:30:11",id:19,status:"hide",title:"cute panda",type:"info",updated_at:"2018-01-11 08:34:11"}
        ];

        csrfData.getArticlesFromDatabase = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(fakeData));

        let app = shallow(<NavList sieve="info" />);
        app.instance().setArticleGroup().then(function() {
            console.log('get state:     ',app.state().articleGroup);
            done();
        }).catch(function() {
            // make your test fail
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but add a new promise seems not great in my case.